# angular material checkbox surrounding div click

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an `angular 5 material checkbox` with a surrounding div and some other elements. I want a click on the `div` to be the same as a `click` directly on the `checkbox`.

Here is my example code:

```
<div (click)="checked = !checked">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checked">
                I'm a not working checkbox :'(                  
  </mat-checkbox>
  <span style="background-color: #dddd00;">I want to be clickable too</span>
</div>
```

and a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyvsxv)

At the moment clicking on the checkbox itself is not working, clicking outside the div works. Any ideas?

Comment: how the save workes on Stackblitz ..seems like not saving my code

Comment: Press the fork button.

Comment: can you try removing `()` around ngModel...

Comment: is that worked ??

Comment: installing same on my end and checking

Comment: hi, provided solution , try if you like it , its working at my end

Comment: See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyvsxv-cy27af). When I click the checkbox it doesn't get checked. Thanks so much for trying!

Comment: i suggested you to keep label out of checkbox tag...as I did in my answer, and it works.. because it seems like problem with that checkbox...this is working : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyvsxv-teyv7t?file=app/checkbox-configurable-example.html

Comment: I can't click on the checkbox. The label works but not the checkbox...

Comment: then try this , its working : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyvsxv-teyv7t?file=app/checkbox-configurable-example.html

Comment: I'm so sorry, but it's not. If I click directly on the [ ] checkbox, it is not getting checked. Is that an Angular bug?

Comment: issue with your code is , you are doing `<div (click)="checked = !checked">` on div and `[(ngModel)]="checked"` on check box that means you are calling two times , so in div click you make checked true same time checkbox ngmodel make checked false ...so you kind of belive its not working ...you need to break that loop

Comment: finally its work : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyvsxv-vltuft?file=app%2Fcheckbox-configurable-example.ts..have look , i made change to ts file also

Comment: hi its working can you please check my answer and also link , and please let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue here is event of `Click` on `div` and `[(ngModel)]` on checkbox both nullify each other thats the reason its not working.

To make it work you need to `stopPropagation`, when you click on div element. so i did code as below `returning false` from div click event that stop it and you code will work.

[**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyvsxv-vltuft)

component.ts

```
export class CheckboxConfigurableExample {
  checked = false;
  indeterminate = false;
  align = 'start';
  disabled = false;

  onChecked() {
  this.checked= !this.checked;
  return false;
  }
}
```

component.thml

```
<mat-card class="result">
    <mat-card-content>
        <h2 class="example-h2">Result</h2>
        <section class="example-section">
            <div (click)="onChecked();">
                <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checked">
          not working checkbox :'( 
                </mat-checkbox>
        <span  style="background-color: #dddd00;">I want to be clickable too</span>
       </div> 

        </section>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this helps with my problem. I know how to use a checkbox ;)

Comment: Now you cannot check the checkbox. Only if you click on the "I want to be clickable too"-Part. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyvsxv-cy27af)

Answer (score 2):

You can also just do this

```
<div (click)="checked = !checked">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checked" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    I'm a not working checkbox :'(
  </mat-checkbox>
  <span style="background-color: #dddd00;">I want to be clickable too</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" on the checkbox did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that:

```
<div (click)="myCheckbox.toggle(); someFunctionWhenChecked(myCheckbox.checked)">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" #myCheckbox (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
                I'm a not working checkbox :'(                  
  </mat-checkbox>
  <span style="background-color: #dddd00;">I want to be clickable too</span>
</div>
```

explanation:

Set a template variable for the checkbox - #myCheckbox, then prevent default behavior when clicking on checkbox so it wont contradict the action made by the div's click event.

On the div's click event just toggle the checkbox's state, and then if you want something to happen when the state is changed use the "someFunctionWhenChecked()" function to pass the new checkbox state.